# Spelling error in home address on ESTA application

Tags: usa, esta

I noticed after approval, I have misspelt Yorkshire (yorkhsire) on my ESTA application. Will it be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

That is obviously a typo, and typos happen.  I don't expect there to be any issue at all with a minor typo - it's not misrepresentation.

*If* you are still particularly worried about it, you could just apply again for your ESTA (and pay again), which will cancel the previous ESTA.  But if you already have your ESTA authorization approved, there is unlikely to be any questions about it when you do travel - particularly over a typo.